# I'm looking for a book I read as a kid about a boy entering fantasy video game

Tags: story-identification, novel

I don't remember much about the book only that I read it sometime around the 2010's . I remember a boy getting sucked into a fantasy video game with his girlfriend . Further, they would level up throughout the novel and at some point he gets a golden armor I think. Later there was also an npc that was a thief who had some chemistry with the protagonist's girlfriend, which made him(the protagonist) jealous. It was more of a kid's/middle schooler book with a few pictures and I'm fairly confident about it being published sometime in the 2000s. Any help would be great :)